# Why a resistor is connected in series with output of IC's?

Tags: resistors, pcb-design

I have seen a PCB schematic. I saw an oscillator and the output clock is connected in **series with a resistor**. I want to know the use of this resistor.
[image: click here for image]

Comment: DNP = Do Not Place, as in "do not put this component on the circuit board", if that helps explain it. Maybe some circuit validation program needed *something* to be there, but in reality the output should be left floating. That would indicate that the validation parameters should be corrected.

Answer (score 2):

> *I saw an oscillator and the output clock is connected in series with a
> resistor. I want to know the use of this resistor.*

More than likely (or even almost certainly) it's to stop reflections. So the output impedance of the chip might be around 20 ohms and, when added to the 33 ohm, the net driving impedance is about 50 ohms. So, if the person designing the PCB has done his/her job correctly and chose the track widths to correspond with a transmission line impedance of 50 ohms, then whatever receives the clock signal (at some distance across the PCB) can be assured that the incoming clock amplitude will be regulated to logic levels reasonably well.

Of course, it's quite possible that the clock chip data sheet tells you to do this so, take a read and see what it says.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of these resistors is almost entirely distinct; however they have in common the fact that they are something that could be changed after the board design is fixed, based on an understanding which may evolve in initial testing.

R184 is the simple to understand case - it allows the option of pulling the "tristate" input up (or even tying it directly to the supply with a zero-ohm jumper in a resistor package) should it be concluded that is desirable.  (It's also possible there are multiple candidates for the oscillator job on the market which have compatible footprints but different requirements for this pin)

R181 is a more complicated situation.  Essentially it functions as *source termination* for a transmission line carrying the high speed clock signal.

A trace on a PC board has a characteristic impedance; if it's a well-designed board, care in routing means that impedance is fairly consistent along the length.  But the source impedance of the driving chip pin is probably lower, and the load impedance of the receiving pin probably higher.  Were the two chips simply connected directly to the trace, sharp edges in the signal could end up reflecting off the impedance discontinuity and bouncing back and forth many times before dying out.

In source termination, the series resistor and the transmission line impedance initially form a voltage divider, and the step which travels down the line at each output change has *half* of the amplitude of the actual output of the pin.  At the far end, the discontinuity of a *higher* impedance causes an in-phase reflection and the voltage is doubled back to its intended value.  That of course is the AC transient analysis - if there is no further change, then one can switch to considering the DC case where the line does not represent a "resistor to ground" so the current through the series resistor is effectively nil and the voltage on the line and at the receiving end is the same as that of the driving pin.

Needless to say that is complicated, and it's not always clear when a board is designed what the best solution will be.  So it has become quite traditional to place the footprint of a resistor at the driver of a high speed line, and often also a series (and possibly shunt) element at the receiver, and then as the initial prototypes are tested the best solution can be found with components experimentally changed out on the bench.  The Bill of Materials is then updated and future examples are manufactured with the seemingly best component choices - which might include any of a matching resistor, a zero-ohm jumper, or (in the case of a shunt element) nothing at all.